# How to bind value to attribute dynamically in typescript Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to get condition value which is coming form exported class in typescript but unable to get for dispay attribute value and on browser it showing me [object HTMLDivElement]

```
@Component({
    template:`<div #noRecordFoundMsg class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix" 
            style="padding:4px 10px;border-bottom: 0 none;display:{{ displayAttribute }}"> <-----here
            <span>{{ noRecordFoundMsg }}</span>
            </div>`})



    private displayAttribute: string;
        exported class Demo{
                   //some code  
            if (Counts === 0) {
                        this.noRecordFoundMsg = "No Record Found";
                        this.displayAttribute = "none";
                    } else {
                        this.displayAttribute = "block";
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried,  `[style.display]="displayAttribute"`:

```
    @Component({
        template:`<div #noRecordFoundMsg class="ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix" 
           [style.display]="displayAttribute"
  style="padding:4px 10px;border-bottom: 0 none;"> <-----here
                <span>{{ noRecordFoundMsg }}</span>
                </div>`})
```

Comment: Yes i tried but still facing same issue :( even also tried [ngStyle]="{'display': displayAttribute}"

Comment: sorry, it should be `[attr.style.display]`

Comment: same issue [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: [style.display]="displayAttribute" is correct. Check the [app.component.ts](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cd4PyX0ZkOjjZn2v6mOI?p=preview), the title has been hidden. @SarveshYadav